# SFTP Connection broken during handshake - remote server stops to reply

Tags: networking, ssh, sftp, winscp

I've been trying to solve this for many hours, I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

I'm trying to connect to the SFTP server. The connection works on all the computers, that I could check except for one.

On this one server, I keep getting timeouts during the handshake. On other computers the "We claim version..." is followed by "Remote version: SSH-2.0-7.9.0.0_openssh GlobalSCAPE" and everything is ok. But here I get some additional communication (see the logs below) which ends up with a timeout.

The ports are open, the firewall does not cause any trouble, tracert reaches the destination server. Filezilla has the same problem.

It looks like the remote is breaking the connection, but what could be the reason for that? All connection parameters seem to be the same as on other machines.

I don't have access to SFTP server logs.

Here is what the WINSCP log is telling me:

```
2023-06-02 17:40:34.432 Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.526 Selecting events 63 for socket 2276 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Waiting for the server to continue with the initialization . 2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Looking for incoming data . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Looking for network events . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.19.2 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Detected network event . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Enumerating network events for socket 2276 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Enumerated 18 network events making 18 cumulative events for socket 2276 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Handling network write event on socket 2276 with error 0 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Handling network connect event on socket 2276 with error 0 . 
2023-06-02 17:40:34.557 Looking for network events . 2023-06-02 17:40:50.990 Timeout waiting for network events
```

Do you have any ideas?